# Codeigniter Prevent "Blank and "SPACE" in text field"

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Codeigniter Prevent "Blank and "SPACE" in text field"

How do i prevent user enter blank and "SPACE" in text field and click "submit" , as when they click on submit it will cause ERROR 400.

The code that I have done

```
$Username=  ($this->input->post("username"))? trim($this->input->post("username"), " ") : "NIL";
```

What I Want: 

 When User enter blank/SPACE it will show error and redirect back to sign up form

Comment: space at the end and start of the string right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `trim` validation rule in your **[CI validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)**, this will remove the extra spaces around the string.

**Second,** you can use `required` validation rule, this will generate an error when input empty.

**Third,** you can also use `min_length[1]` rule in validation, this will work like that:

```
<?php
if (isset($this->input->post("username")) && strlen(trim($this->input->post("username"))) > 0){
    // success
}
else{
    // error
}
```

So, complete validation rule should looks like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username','required|trim|min_length[1]');
```

Comment: I will try it when i back on my computer , will update result soon

Comment: sorry for the late response , yeah i did tried and it works , cheers mate .